# Grails many to one and belongsTo

Tags: grails, relational-database, relationship

Let's say I have two domain objects as seen below,

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    String name
}

class Book {
    String title
    static belongsTo=[author:Author]
}
```

If I wanted to create a `Book`, I will have to create an `Author` first and if I wanted to create an `Author` I will need to create some `books`. So would I have to create a `Book` and `Author` at the same time?

Comment: An `Author` does not require any `Books` to exist. Create it first. `hasMany` is 0:N (zero to N-number).

Answer (score 0):

An `Author` does not require any `Books` to exist. Create the `Author` first. `hasMany` is a 0:N (zero to N-number) relationship.